# all Arabs, Iraqis Afghans are Hajj

Tags: word-usage

The speaker appears to have used "Hajj" as a collective term for all Muslims (while normally Hajj is officially defined as the pilgrimage by a Muslin to Mecca). Am I on the right track?

> Anyway you take this empty vessel and you scare the living shit out of him, break him down to nothing, cultivate a brotherhood and camaraderie with those he suffers with,  and fill his head with racist nonsense like **all Arabs, Iraqis Afghans are Hajj.** Hajj hates you. Hajj wants to hurt your family. Hajj children are the worst because they beg all the time. Just some of the most hurtful and ridiculous propaganda, but you'd be amazed at how effective it's been in fostering my generation of soldiers.

> Source: The Untold History of the United States pp582
> (This thread is following [the previous thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/280965/take-an-empty-shell-off-the-streets?noredirect=1#comment523995_280965) - the content is an excerpt from an American soldier's memory)

Comment: Whatever the speaker means, it's not standard usage.  At first, it looks like they're using "Hajj" as a name, but then it's used as an adjective ("Hajj children").  In standard English, you, if you could use *Hajjis* to mean *people who are or have been on the pilgrimage to Mecca*.  But it doesn't seem like that's what the speaker means, anyway.

Comment: It's a slang term for Muslims.  I hate to link to Urban Dictionary, but in this case it is useful: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Haji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That American soldier has no idea what "Hajj" might actually mean. In this context it has nothing to do with the pilgrimage. Yes, he could have said "Muslims". I think here "Hajj" is a derogatory term for this group, like "w..p" or "k..e" or "n...r" for Italian or Jewish or Black.

You will find lots of vernacular in this source that you can't easily parse as standard English. Keep asking.

Comment: Since you are (quite understandably) uncomfortable naming racial slurs, I might suggest you omit them completely and just refer to "other derogatory terms." There is no need to give specific examples, and I'm intrigued that you censored only one of your examples.

Comment: @TypeIA I thought about that. I decided the OP should perhaps know the others, should they encounter them. They also feel (to me) somewhat less offensive. It was a hard call and worth commenting on.

Comment: @TypeIA I've now censored them all.

Comment: I saw that; I never downvoted though if that's why you're cueing me. (For what it's worth, I personality think removing the examples completely would be better than censoring them... there's no value in having them now. Better to spell them all out or delete the list.)

Comment: @TypeIA I fixed it because you convinced me (that far), not to reverse a downvote.